# How do I change Windows Service environment path

Tags: .net, windows, service, environment-variables

I need to change thw environment variable Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TMP") for a Windows service in .NET 2.0 that is running with its own user account. The server is a Windows Server 2003, SP2. Can anybody tell me how to change the Windows environment variable for that user?

Comment: No, I do need to change it in Windows, probably in the registry?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just set the environment variable in your Main or OnStart method:

```
  Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("TMP", @"c:\temp");
```

Using SetEnvironmentVariable() changes the environment only for the running instance of the process, it doesn't change the user's system environment.